# Variable inside asset function not rendering in blade template engine in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've tried both but the variable $image->name is not rendering.

```
{!! asset('uploads/posts/thumbnails/$image->name') !!}
{{ asset('uploads/posts/thumbnails/$image->name') }}
```

it out puts the html as follows

```
<img src="http://localhost/blog/uploads/posts/thumbnails/$image->name/">
```

I don't want to use this

```
{{asset('uploads/posts/thumbnails')}}/{{ $image->name }}
```

Is there any other way?

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the variable out of the string literal, because it get treated as a string, not a variable:

```
{!! asset('uploads/posts/thumbnails/' . $image->name) !!}
```

Or use double quote `"` (it parses the variables in it)

```
{!! asset("uploads/posts/thumbnails/$image->name") !!}
```

Comment: @user3407278 If the solution works for you, you can mark the answer as accepted, by clicking on the green thick mark.

Comment: I tried but It says that I have to wait 6+ minutes to mark your answer.